# Can I fish low voltage cables through my plumbing chase?

Tags: cables

Generally speaking, is it a good idea to fish low voltage cables through a plumbing chase?

I want to specify that I was wondering about using the same cavity (A plumbing chase), not using the actual plumbing vent (DVW Pipe) itself.

Comment: I think the answers need a clarification; do mean inside the pipe itself, or just in the wall cavity next to the pipe?

Comment: I mean sharing the wall cavity.

Comment: @not_entirely_recommended. -- a-ha

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel - an addendum would've been better than deleting or editing outright your answer. It's N/A, but "IPC 901.4 (aka IRC P3101.3)" is what to look for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can run low voltage and even mains voltage in the same cavity your plumbing is using.

I say this with the understanding that the cable is rated for the chase construction (some made out of brick / concrete the cable would have to be listed for use enclosed in brick or concrete).